# OC Setter method

Tags: ios, setter

Here are two ways that better?I do not understand...

Thank you!

```
- (void)setName:(NSString *)name
{
    //one way
    [_name release];
    [name retain];
    _name = name;

    //another way
    //[_name autorelease];
    //_name = [name retain];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is the same but the first one is better from point of performance and multithreading.

The autorelease pool will take some extra resources, put the object onto some stack which calls release in the next thread cycle. If you are using this in other then main thread you also need to create the autorelease pool or the object will be leaking.

The autorelease is very useful in some getter methods where you create the returned object to make sure it will be released after some time and not on the fly as you might need to prolong its lifetime:

```
- (NSObject *)generateObject {
    //good
    return [[[NSObject alloc] init] autorelease];

    //will be deallocated on the fly
    NSObject *toReturn = [NSObject alloc] init];
    [toReturn release];
    return toReturn;
}
```

The second approach will deallocate the object as soon as calling release which means the method is useless. The first approach will work and by using `object = [[self generateObject] retain]` you will retake the ownership of the object and will not be deallocated until another `release` or `autorelease` is called on it. Do note that you do not need to retake the ownership if the lifetime of the object is shorter then the thread cycle, that means if you will not pass it as some parameter in object which will use it later or use it on some other thread.

You should know this differences for scenarios such as using loops: If you iterate through lets say 100 images using `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:]` your application will most likely be killed due to large memory consumptions because all 100 images will be in memory at the end of the loop because they are being autoreleased. On the other hand using `[[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:] release]` will deallocate the image data on the fly and will work as expected.

So in general you I suggest you to use the `autorelease` only when there is no other way. If possible try to release the objects on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)setName:(NSString *)name
{
  // this is best practice which recommended by Apple 
  // this would be better
  [_name release]; // _name variable is released 
  [name retain];   // name variable increase retain count 
  _name = name;    // _name variable is pointed to name

// just another way
// [_name autorelease];   // _name variable will be released but don't know when this happens (maybe circle of memory management)
// _name = [name retain];
}
```